# Random value in array when defining from function (Arduino)

Tags: arrays, function, arduino

I am currently making an arduino library in which I need to be able to define an array from argument in a fonction like : `OpenMenuOS menu("Flashlight", "Profile", "Heat", "Reflow", "Settings", "Wifi", "Colis", "Survival", "Autres");` but when I print the array to the serial , it gives me something like that :

```
Menu Items:
Item 1: Flashlight
Item 2: Profile
Item 3: Heat
Item 4: Reflow
Item 5: Settings
Item 6: Wifi
Item 7: Colis
Item 8: Survival
Item 9: Autres
Item 10: ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿøÚÆ\
Item 11: øÚÆ\
Item 12: 
Item 13: ðü?
Item 14: ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿD<þ?
Item 15: D<þ?
Item 16: 6a
```

The fonction used in the library is :

```
OpenMenuOS::OpenMenuOS(const char* names...) {
  num_menu_items = 0;
  va_list args;
  va_start(args, names);
  const char* name = names;
  while (name != NULL) {
    strncpy(menu_items[num_menu_items], name, MAX_ITEM_LENGTH);
    name = va_arg(args, const char*);
    num_menu_items++;
  }
  va_end(args);
}
```

Does anyone knows what the problem is?
Here is a link to the Wokwi Simulation : https://wokwi.com/projects/390361308680986625

I tried adding more arguments to the function to try to counter the effect, but that seemed to make it worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to pass the terminator `NULL` after the last element.

```cpp
OpenMenuOS menu(
    "Flashlight",
    "Profile",
    "Heat",
    "Reflow",
    "Settings",
    "Wifi",
    "Colis",
    "Survival",
    "Autres",
    NULL // add this to tell the function where is the end of arguments
);
```

Comment: It works but, how could I modify the function to automatically add the NULL at the end?